# Batch For Loop not working for a list of Folders

Tags: batch-file

To keep it short, i want to create list of folders in a directory to make it easier for the user to pick a folder.

Here is what i have:

```
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...

set /a Ocount=0

for /d %%a in (...\listofoptions\*) do (

     set /a count+=1
     set Option !count!=%%a
     echo Option !count! - %%a
)
```

...
...
...

But my problem is that Option 0 is being set to the last folder in the list and it's the only variable being created, but count is being echo'd correctly. I was a list of variables named 'OPTION #'...
 when i enter 'set o' in the in my command line only Option 0 shows up.

```
Option 0 = last folder
Ocount = 26
```

Comment: Don't edit the code in your question to fix errors that are pointed out in an answer - this destroys the context of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Echo Off
Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Set Count=0

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /ad /b c:\windows') do (
Set /a "Count=Count + 1"
Echo !Count! %%A 
)
```

As you had `echo off` you didn't see the message that your `SelLocal` command was wrong (misspelt and wrong casing).

This is meaningless `(...\listofoptions\\`. `...` is a Novell OS standard for parent's parent. Not supported by current windows. `\\` means at the start of a string that it is followed by a UNC style path.

`count+=1` needs a `set /a` in front of it.

This gives you a dialog

```
on error resume next
Set bffShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set bff = bffShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the My Documents folder", 9)
If Err.number<>0 Then
        MsgBox "Error Setting up Browse for Folder"
    Else
        A = bff.ParentFolder.ParseName(bff.Title).Path
        If err.number=424 then err.clear
        wscript.echo A
End If
```

Name it bff.vbs

To use

```
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo "c:\folder\bff.vbs"') Do echo %%A
```

Comment: \\ was a typo, i didn't catch it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @CubanBeans - You should never have typos in your question code - You should be using copy and paste on code that you have verified as accurately demonstrating your problem.

Comment: The statement *"As you had echo off you didn't see the message that your SelLocal command was wrong (misspelt and wrong casing)."* has two serious falsehoods. Setting ECHO OFF does not hide error messages. And the syntax for commands and options ignores case (except for FOR variables). Also, extra \ generally do not cause problems, though they certainly should be avoided.